# Accessing a image view via tags

Tags: java, android, androiddesignsupport

I am working on an android project in which i have created 3 linear layouts( horizontal) and each layout has some image views . I also assigned tags for each image view.
How can i acces each image view via tags .
I want access it for checking different conditions of image view.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags are not used to identify views, So you cant used it direct to identify views (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

You need to get the parent first.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_layout_1);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewWithTag("imageTag");
```